# Finding minimum initial velocity and angle for a projectile to reach a given point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I need to analytically find the **minimum** initial velocity, $v_0$, and angle, $\Theta$, for a projectile with initial position $(0,0)$ to reach the point $(d,h)=(5.53,3.6)$.

So far I've come up with the following equation:
$$S(t) = S\underset{0}{} + v_0\dot{}(\cos\Theta,\sin\Theta)t+(0,g)\dot{}\frac{t^2}{2}$$

$S(t)$ is the function that gives us the position of the projectile at time $t$, $S_0$ being the initial position $(0,0)$, where $v_0$ is the unknow initial velocity, $\Theta$ the unknow initial launch angle and $g$ is gravity $= -9.8$.

I threw that equation at [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m6kifxr4tc) and by playing around with $v_0$ and $\Theta$ with three significant figures I got:
$v_0 = 10.0$
$\Theta = 1.06$

The problem is that now I need to solve $v_0$ for $g, h$ and $d$; and $\Theta$ for $h$ and $d$ and check if I got everything right. I have no idea on how I'm going to do this.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: @WojciechMorawiec That graph has $v_0 = 11.95$ which is higher than $10$, which was the $v_0$ I found. They key factor in this question is that I need to find the minimum value and not just a value,If you play around with the sliders you'll notice that 10 is the lowest value with three significant figures that you can use to reach that point.

Comment: @sammygerbil Not a duplicate since that question only $\Theta$ is an unknow whilst everything else is given.

Comment: Fair point. I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @LuisPais Ah, excuse me - I've somehow overread the bold "minimum", don't ask how. Have you tried using the two equations to get one equation for $v_0(\theta, t)$ which you can then minimize with respect to $\theta$?

Comment: @WojciechMorawiec Your suggestion was correct and was what sammy said in his answer, I needed to join both equation and minimize $v_0(\Theta)$ by replacing $t$ = $\frac{x}{v_0\dot{}{}\cos(\Theta)}$ in the second equation.  
Thank you !

Comment: @LuisPais Congratulations! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for the [trajectory of the projectile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Height_at_x) is
$y=x\tan\theta-\frac{g}{2v^2\cos^2\theta}x^2$.
You are given the target co-ordinates $(x,y)$ and wish to find the minimum value of $v$ as $\theta$ is varied.

Rearrange this equation to find $v^2$ as a function of $\theta$, with $(x,y)$ as constants. (It is good enough to multiply through by $2\cos^2\theta=1+\cos2\theta$ so that terms in $v$ and $\theta$ are separated.) Then differentiate and set $\frac{dv}{d\theta}=0$ to find when $v$ is a minimum. This will give you the optimum value for $\theta$; substitute back into the original equation to find the miniumum $v$. Check that you have obtained a minimum and not a maximum.

Comment: And how exactly did you get to that equation ?
It's giving a diferent graph compared to mine.

Comment: It is a standard result. eg http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/trajectory_formula/162/ or http://formulas.tutorvista.com/physics/trajectory-formula.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Height_at_x

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to square cos.  
That equation is derived from the initial equation that is in my question by using both equations to create one and your suggestion on minimizing is the same as @Wojciech 's, which I'm confident will give me the result I'm looking for. I'll post back soon.

Comment: Note that $\theta \gt 45^{\circ}$. I get the neat result that $v^2=gx^2/(L-y)$ where $L^2=x^2+y^2$. and $\tan2\theta=-x/y$.

Comment: I solved $y(x)$ for $v(\Theta)$, differentiated and I got a really messed up function but in the end I got my optimum results, which where around 1.06 and 10.0, or 1.07 and 9.99.  
Thank you !